# Как в GTK+ рисовать графики?

Tags: c, gtk+, графики

Как в **GTK+** нарисовать линию или хотя бы точку где бы то ни было: на форме, на изображении, на кнопке - не суть важно.

Comment: Рисуйте в буфере, потом скармливайте его GTK. Я думаю, вам надо смотреть в сторону класса Canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов отрисовки использовать объект типа ***gtk_drawing_area***
На этом объекте можно рисовать с использованием примитивов библиотеки [cairo](https://cairographics.org/)

[Не большой пример отрисовки индикатора](https://pastebin.com/U9Lvh81k)

Также можно использовать объект ***gtk_image*** на нем отображать объект ***gtk_pixbuf*** , а это любые растровые изображения. И также объект ***gtk_pixbuf*** можно редактировать с использованием библиотеки  [cairo](https://cairographics.org/)

Comment: “Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”

Comment: Большое спасибо, первый толковый пример, который мне удалось получить за несколько дней поисков!